# Apigee Timeout not connecting to GKE privately using Cloud DNS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, apigee

GCP demo project so there is only one **Default** VPC.

i created the Apigee and it got created to us-west1 with default VPC peering to my project and **Default VPC**.

i have **GKE** running with **VPC native** & **Cloud DNS** with VPC scope, which mean all SVC records being exported to **Cloud DNS**.

So i created the **GKE** in **us-central** and deployed simple **nginx** deployment with **Headless** **service**.

Gin Apigee side created simple **hello-world** pointing to **Google.com** worked like charm.

but when i try adding destination of api google to the `http://nginx-svc.default.svc.gkeapi.` to it was failing with **TARGET_CONNECT_HOST_NOT_REACHABLE** i did the **DNS peering**.

```
gcloud services peered-dns-domains create gke-apigee --network=default --dns-suffix=gkeapi.
```

My **apigee**, **GKE**, **Cloud DNS** everything is part of single project and which has single **VPC** **default** only.

Now it's giving error **TARGET_CONNECT_TIMEOUT**, which mean it's not able to resolve the IP address to GKE, while it's also in same **VPC** default region **us-west** zone **us-west1-a**.

i did tried creating simple **private** **VM** to same project and accessing the **DNS** record `nginx-svc.default.svc.gkeapi.` from there it's working like charm.

Not sure, why **apigee** throwing the **Timeout** error.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue.  Ended up needing to add a firewall policy to allow `tcp:80` for the Apigee instance IP range.